# Passing arrays in ajax call using jQuery 1.4

Tags: jquery

The following code works for me using jQuery 1.2.6 but causes a broker error in 1.4.

```
var items = new Array();
items[0] = "Item 1";
items[1] = "Item 2";
items[2] = "Item 3";

var dataToSend = {'_service' : myService, '_program' : myProgram, 'selections' : items} ;

$.ajax({    
 type: "post",
 url: myURL,
 dataType: "text",
 data: dataToSend,
 success: function(request) {$('#results').html(request); } // End success
}); // End ajax method
```

The broker error I get indicates that what is being passed in selections is 'selections[]'

ERROR:*(Invalid character "[" in field name "selections[]". This character is not allowed in field names.)*

Was there a change in how jQuery handles arrays in an ajax call? or was this an incorrect way to pass an array?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The answer from @jvenema solved my problem. With the "traditional" setting you can cause jQuery to handle the parameters like the previous version. Here are some additional links which talk about the change [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) and a blog post [jQuery 1.4 $.param demystified](http://benalman.com/news/2009/12/jquery-14-param-demystified/).

Either a general statement of

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

or as an additional option in the ajax call

```
$.ajax({    
 traditional: true,
 type: "post",
 url: myURL,
 dataType: "text",
 data: dataToSend,
 success: function(request) {
   $('#results').html(request);
 }  // End success
}); // End ajax method
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

jQuery 1.4 was updated to use the PHP syntax for sending arrays. You can switch it into the old style by using:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetting.traditional = true;
```

See [here](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards) for details.

Comment: Also, you should mention the way to do it for a single Ajax call: add traditional:true to the $.Ajax object.

Comment: Is there any way to get this result with `getJSON()` or must I use `ajax()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the array as Json array.

> ```
> 'selections' : {items : ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']}
> ```

I think that this will work too.

> ```
> 'selections' : {items : items}
> ```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255216/why-doesnt-jquery-turn-my-array-into-a-json-string-before-sending-to-asp-net-web) for addition resource.