# Servlet Receive Complete Array on index[0]

Tags: jquery, arrays, servlets

I am sending array from jQuery to Servlet.For table I am using [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) API. The following is code snippet:

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#savePO").click(function(){

    var oTable = $('#npoGridView').dataTable();
    var  getdata = oTable.fnGetData()

    $.post("AddPO" ,{
        getData: escape(getdata)
    },
    function (data)
    {   
        alert(data);
    });


});
```

**Servlet:**

```
String []getResult = request.getParameterValues("getData");
```

Servlet receive all the data on index [0],(i.e. getResult[0] ), even number of row are more than one;

How can we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the traditional style of [param serialization](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). Using $.ajax call you could simply do:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "AddPO",
  data: escape(getdata),
  traditional: true,
  success: function (data)
    {   
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/
- [Passing arrays in ajax call using jQuery 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195471/passing-arrays-in-ajax-call-using-jquery-1-4)