# How to pass a JSON array in javascript to my codebehind file

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, json

I am getting a JSON object in my javascript function in aspx page. I need to fetch this data from my code behind file. How can I do it?

My javascript function is :

```
 function codeAddress() 
    {
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();            
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: results[0].geometry.location });
            }
            else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }

            var requestParameter = '{' +
                        'output:"' + results + '"}';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
                data: requestParameter,
                //contentType: "plain/text",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);

                }, 
                error: function() { alert("error"); } 
            });

        });
    }


   Default.aspx.cs

 [WebMethod]
public static string  GetData( Object   output) 
{
    return output.ToString();
}
```

I am getting the output as an array of objects instead of the actual result -   [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] .Please provide me a solution to get the actual result.  The JSON I am working on is given below 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=M%20G%20Road&sensor=false

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post an array of complex objects with JSON, jQuery to ASP.NET MVC Controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-control)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a WebMethod on your aspx Page that get the array on the page as:

```
[WebMethod]
public static GetData( type[] arr)  // type could be "string myarr" or int type arrary - check this
{}
```

and  make json request.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'Default.aspx/GetData',
  data: "{'backerEntries':" + backerEntries.toString() + "}",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {}
});
```

or you can use .post().

Check the `url:` in ajax request `GetData` WebMethod must be declared on the `Default.aspx` on that page where you are making ajax request.

**Check this question to know that how to format array for sending to the web method.**
[Why doesn't jquery turn my array into a json string before sending to asp.net web method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255216/why-doesnt-jquery-turn-my-array-into-a-json-string-before-sending-to-asp-net-we)

Check these links for reference:
[Handling JSON Arrays returned from ASP.NET Web Services with jQuery](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/96/Handling-JSON-Arrays-returned-from-ASP.NET-Web-Services-with-jQuery) - It is Best to take idea
[How to post an array of complex objects with JSON, jQuery to ASP.NET MVC Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-control)